# Slack CLI app vs app created in UI (https://api.slack.com/apps)?

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands, slack-block-kit

What is the difference between the app created using the commands '[create](https://api.slack.com/automation/cli/commands#create)' and '[deploy](https://api.slack.com/automation/cli/commands#platform-deploy)' versus the one created using the [UI](https://api.slack.com/apps)?

Can the app created using the UI be managed using the CLI commands? If so, what are the steps? Thanks!